# group trs for hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to group tr's in a table so when you hover over lets say five of them the hover function is fired?

I can do this individually but I would like 5 rows to act as one group. So anywhere in that 5 rows the hover is in affect. When you hover out it goes away.

I am currently using this for individual rows.

```
$('#second_step tr').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background','#eff0ef');
},function(){
    $(this).css('background','#fff');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can group rows in `<tbody />` tags.  according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) a table can contain "zero or more tbody elements"

```
$('#second_step tbody').hover(function() {
    $(this).children().css('background','#eff0ef');
},function(){
    $(this).children().css('background','#fff');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You should group each set of 5 rows in a separate `<tbody>`, then apply the hover effect to the `<tbody>`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#second_step tr.particular').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background','#eff0ef');
},function(){
    $(this).css('background','#fff');
});
```

You can assign a class to the ones you want to be highlighted on hover and attach the event to that.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: It's the best option I could find to solve the problem... this way they don't have to be bound to a particular tbody.